# How to communicate with a Unix terminal from a Java program on Windows

Tags: java, linux, unix, ssh

I am writing a Java program on a Windows PC, that needs to communicate with several applications on our company's Unix machines.

The program I developed contains a Swing interface with a JButton. For the moment, when I click on the button, I can select a directory like "C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents" on my machine. Here is the code sample :

```
selectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            // Choose a directory 
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
            chooser.setDialogTitle("choosertitle");
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

            if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
              System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
              System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " + chooser.getSelectedFile());
            } else {
              System.out.println("No Selection ");
            }
        }
    });
```

Now I would like to select a directory in another machine working with Unix (let's say the machine name is "unix-service") instead of a directory on my local machine. So when I click on the button :

- I need to know the group of the user in our company to continue. In a Unix terminal, we can do it with the command "echo $WORK_GROUP". I want to save this user's group as a variable "user_group"
- I want to select a directory "workgroug/user_group/username/" on that Unix machine.

How can I do it using ssh commands and adapting my code ?

I hope everything is clear and explained, do not hesitate to ask me if you need more information. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. You know of a possible solution (use SSH in Java) but have made no attempt to implement it.

Comment: Actually I found some examples with ssh but no one of them seems to do what I want or help me to do what I want. That's why I am asking the exact problem to have some hints.

Comment: I get what your problem is but the answer to your problem is to use a library for Java that does ssh or maybe a library that does scp or ftp. And the answers are just recommending those libraries, which can be found by doing a google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use java ssh API from following library to connect to remote box.

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

A good example is provided here to execute a command on remote Linux/UNIX system using SSH

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html

Answer (score 0):

So, you just need to get access a unix box through JAVA. There are many libraries doing that job.
Have a look here: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

"JSch is a pure Java implementation of SSH2. JSch allows you to connect to an sshd server and use port forwarding, X11 forwarding, file transfer, etc., and you can integrate its functionality into your own Java programs."

Comment: Not reason to downvote,I was typing the question while the other one came up first. Don't lose your temper and your manners people!

Comment: I just up-voted you ;). We both have same thoughts about solution.